# make a loading spinner disappear afer x seconds

Tags: css, hide, loader

i have started to learn HTML and CSS last december. Now, i have to finish a project using only HTML and CSS, no Javascipt or other languages. I have fullfilled all the requirements of the projects but it's now 5 days i am stuck on a problem which will look easy to solve for many of you. So, when the main page is loading, a loading spinner is required (creating one was not a problem). The problem for me is to make the spinner disappear after x seconds). i have tried and tried and tried and i did not succeed yet. my last attempt is bellow, the resultas are: the spinner disapear but a big white "panel" cover the top of the main page. here is the html code (the area concerned): many thanks for your help

```css
.parent__spinner{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity:1;
    animation: fade;
    animation-duration: 0s;
    animation-delay:3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }


.loading__spiner{/*création du loader*/
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-top:20px solid $couleur-primaire;
  border-bottom: 20px solid $couleur-secondaire;
  border-radius: 50%;/*arrondi des angles*/
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin: auto;/*placement milieu de page*/
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  animation-name:spin;
  animation-duration:3s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      visibility:visible;
    }
    50%{
      transform: rotate(180deg);
      visibility:visible;
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
      visibility:hidden;
      display:none;
      height:0;
      width:0;

  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from{
    opacity:1;
  }
  to{
    opacity:0;
    z-index:-100;
    display:none;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    clip-path:circle(0);/* rognage de la totalité donc disparition*/
  }
   }

@keyframes monanim {
from{
  overflow:hidden;
}
to{
  overflow:visible;
}
 }


.body {
  animation: monanim;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
  <body class="body">

        <div class="parent__spinner">
            <div class="loading__spiner"></div>
        </div>

        <header class="header__index">
```

Comment: I tested your code, but I could not see **big white "panel"**. Maybe that is the continue of your html code that you did not posted to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In "fade" animation, its "From" Property I add "display: block" & in "To" I add "display: none" for hide "parent__spinner" this tag.

```css
.parent__spinner{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity:1;
    animation: fade;
    animation-duration: 0s;
    animation-delay:3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }


.loading__spiner{/*création du loader*/
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-top:20px solid red;
  border-bottom: 20px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;/*arrondi des angles*/
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin: auto;/*placement milieu de page*/
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  animation-name:spin;
  animation-duration:3s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      visibility:visible;
    }
    50%{
      transform: rotate(180deg);
      visibility:visible;
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
      visibility:hidden;
    
      height:0;
      width:0;

  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from{
    opacity:1;
    display: block;
  }
  to{
    opacity:0;
    z-index:-100;
    display:none;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    display: none;
    clip-path:circle(0);/* rognage de la totalité donc disparition*/
  }
   }

@keyframes monanim {
from{
  overflow:hidden;
}
to{
  overflow:visible;
}
 }


.body {
  animation: monanim;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body  class="body">
     

        <div class="parent__spinner">
            <div class="loading__spiner"></div>
        </div>
    

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>


    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.
it works but there is a small problem: the loading spinner apprears (perfect), then the scroll bar appears ( and i want it to appears simoultaniusly with the main page), then the main page appears.
Any solution please?
Thank you.

```css
.parent__spinner{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity:1;
    animation: fade;
    animation-duration: 0s;
    animation-delay:3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }


.loading__spiner{/*création du loader*/
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-top:20px solid red;
  border-bottom: 20px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;/*arrondi des angles*/
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin: auto;/*placement milieu de page*/
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  animation-name:spin;
  animation-duration:3s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      visibility:visible;
    }
    50%{
      transform: rotate(180deg);
      visibility:visible;
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
      visibility:hidden;
    
      height:0;
      width:0;

  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from{
    opacity:1;
    display: block;
  }
  to{
    opacity:0;
    z-index:-100;
    display:none;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    display: none;
    clip-path:circle(0);/* rognage de la totalité donc disparition*/
  }
   }

@keyframes monanim {
from{
  overflow:hidden;
}
to{
  overflow:visible;
}
 }


.body {
  animation: monanim;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body  class="body">
     

        <div class="parent__spinner">
            <div class="loading__spiner"></div>
        </div>
    

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>


    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this answer is actually a comment on the first answer. I suggest that you withdraw it and just post your comment

Comment: I think this is really a *comment* on the first answer, not an independent answer.  I suggest you withdraw it and post a comment instead